# Pass arguments to Python script to jar/Java

Tags: python, java, subprocess

I have a Python script that uses variables such as an email address and a message.
I need to pass that data from the Python script to the Java jar.

I can run the jar from Python with:

```python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'JavaEmail.jar'])
```

I need to pass variables such as email_address and a file.txt to the following Java program:

```java
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;


public class JavaEmail{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String to = "receive@abc.om";            // sender email
        String from = "sender@abc.com";       // receiver email
        String host = "127.0.0.1";                   // mail server host

       Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); 
        // default session
        System.out.println(to);
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);        
            // email message

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
            // setting header fields
           
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, 
                               new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Test Mail from Java Program"); // subject line

            // actual mail body
            message.setText("");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass the values as commandline parameters to your Java program. Then in your Java program you extract the commandline parameters and use them.

Comment: You could just pass them as application arguments. Then the values would be in the `args` array. For example, if you executed `java -jar JavaEmail.jar foo@example.com`, then `args[0]` would return `"foo@example.com"`. Translate that to the Python subprocess call arguments list as needed.

Comment: Have you tried something like `subprocess.call(['java', '-jar', 'JavaEmail.jar', 'paramtojava1', 'paramtojava2'])`?

Comment: You don't need Java to send an email message; Pyton provides `email` and `smtplib`, or just run `sendmail` in a subprocess.